# AuFS read only branch as another read only branch

Tags: mount, read-only, aufs

My goal is to use an AuFS read only branch as another read only branch:

I've got a directory `dir0`, then I make :

```
mount -t aufs -o br=dir2=rw:dir0=ro none dir1
```

This gives me

```
- dir0
- dir1  #read only dir0
- dir2  #write layer of dir1
```

I now want to use `dir1` this way:

```
mount -t aufs -o br=dir4=rw:dir1=ro none dir3
```

To get

```
- dir0
- dir1  #read only dir0
- dir2  #write layer of dir0
- dir3  #read only dir1 (dir1 + dir2)
- dir4  #write layer of dir3
```

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and this should work according to aufs-tools man page:

> Any filesystem can be a branch, But some are not  accepted  such
>                 like sysfs, procfs and unionfs.  If you specify such filesystems
>                 as an aufs branch, aufs  will  return  an  error  saying  it  is
>                 unsupported.

But I got this error:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
>          need a /sbin/mount. helper program)
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

and `dmesg` gives me

> aufs test_add:231:mount[3346]: unsupported filesystem,  (aufs)

Am I missing something here ?
Regards,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is currently not possible.

However, Overlayfs does it very well and seems to be the union FS of choice in ubuntu and in the future 3.10 Linux kernel.